# comparing two text files using python

Tags: python

i'm trying to compare two text files and to identify and save the different lines in a new text file, but i dont know how to do it because im very very new to Python. Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to specify your problem more clearly as there are lots of ways to consider two files different or identical. For example, does the order of the lines matter? Are you looking for lines that are *different* or lines that are *only in one of the two files*  or both?

Comment: The proposed duplicate specifically says he does not care about what the differences are. This question is specifically about identifying the precise differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using linux, you might try some command like: `diff`

and this is for [python diff doc](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html)